# PHP json_encode to AJAX, undefined

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I'm new at AJAX and I am just trying to display the database results from PHP to HTML via AJAX. I'm getting "undefined" on console log when I load the page. HTML, PHP and the JS files are separated from each other.

Here's my JS Code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$.ajax({

    type: "GET",
    url:  "xaja.php",
    dataType: "json",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",

    success: function(data){
        console.log(""+data.name);
    },
    error: function(e){
        alert("Error:\n"+e);
    }

});

});
```

Here's my PHP Code:

```
<?php

$json = array(

'username' => '',
'name' => '',
'loc' => ''

);


$sql = "Select * from tbluser";
$query = mysql_query($sql, $conn);
$result = mysql_fetch_assoc($query);

do{
    $json['username'] = $result['username'];
    $json['name'] = $result['name'];
    $json['loc'] = $result['location'];
    echo json_encode($json);
    $result = mysql_fetch_assoc($query);

}
while($result);

?>
```

Am I missing something here? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Use `console.log` instead of `alert` to debug Javascript - `alert` only handles strings or string-like values, `console.log` can output nearly anything.  You'll be able to see what the value of `e` is (an object) and debugging will become much easier.

Comment: Thanks Scott, here's the error now: Object { readyState: 4, getResponseHeader: .ajax/v.getResponseHeader(), getAllResponseHeaders: .ajax/v.getAllResponseHeaders(), setRequestHeader: .ajax/v.setRequestHeader(), overrideMimeType: .ajax/v.overrideMimeType(), statusCode: .ajax/v.statusCode(), abort: .ajax/v.abort(), state: .Deferred/d.state(), always: .Deferred/d.always(), then: .Deferred/d.then(), 11 more… }

Comment: It tells me undefined.

Comment: You are sending of countless responses due to the while loop. Try gathering the json-arrays of yours in a superset array and do a single response.

Comment: e.message should work. Or try e.name. Both should be supported by all browsers!

Comment: Actually, the jQuery ajax error return looks like this: `error
Type: Function( jqXHR jqXHR, String textStatus, String errorThrown )` so try `.error(e, textStatus, errorThrown) {console.log(errorThrown);}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are outputting multiple json strings.  In order for your respond to be parsed it needs to be a single string.  Try this instead:

```
$results = array();
do{
    $json['username'] = $result['username'];
    $json['name'] = $result['name'];
    $json['loc'] = $result['location'];
    $results[] = $json;
    $result = mysql_fetch_assoc($query);
}
while($result);
echo json_encode($results);
```

Comment: still getting an object object.

Comment: It's now successful, but still getting an undefined data on console.log :(

Comment: What does it output when you do `console.log(data);`?

Comment: "[object Object],[object Object]" - and yeah I have 2 data in my database.

Comment: Are you adding a "". or something inside the console.log or something?  I ask because when you just do a `console.log(data)` it should actually show you the object data

Comment: sorry, i just removed it. Here's what I'm getting now:
Array [ Object, Object, Object ]

Comment: In your browser when you look at the console it should let you expand the objects and see their data.  Take a look at one of them and you should see what properties are available to them

Comment: I can see the results now. Finally! Thanks cj! :)

Answer (score 0):

why not traditional way?

```
$sql = "Select * from tbluser";
$query = mysql_query($sql, $conn);

if ($result = mysql_fetch_assoc($query) ) {
    $json['username'] = $result['username'];
    $json['name'] = $result['name'];
    $json['loc'] = $result['location'];
    echo json_encode($json);
}
```

or if you need array of array:

```
$json = array();
$sql = "Select * from tbluser";
$query = mysql_query($sql, $conn);

while ($result = mysql_fetch_assoc($query) ) {
    $json[] = array($result['username'], $result['name'], $result['location']);
}
echo json_encode($json);
```

Answer (score 0):

When returning JSON it should be a single structure, instead of outputting an array for each row, you should rather be building the array and outputting it once.

```
$json = array();
do {
    $json[]=$result;
    $result = mysql_fetch_assoc($query);
} while($result);
echo json_encode($json);
```

Which shows each row as a named structure (`[{username:"",name:"",location:""},{}..]`)